# "Error: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 66653 > 65536)" when generating a signed apk

Tags: java, android

I am trying to generate a signed apk so I can export my app to the Google Play store. However I keep getting the same error. Is there anything to fix this.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.sean.monacoball"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:12.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    }
}
```

Error in depth :

[image: Error]

Comment: Err, do you actually have these thousands and thousands of methods in your classes?

Comment: No, I am just using these dependencies for google interstitial ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Google Play services setup guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split):

> Note: Don't use the combined `play-services` target. It brings in dozens of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.

As you're using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1`, you're pulling in **every** Google Play services library. You should switch to only using the libraries you actually use. This will almost certainly put you under the [64k method limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex) of a single dex file.

Comment: How do you know which google play libraries I should use and how can I integrate them into my code.

Comment: @pfftkhaganate - the setup guide has the list of all of the libraries along with what is included in them - `play-services-cast` includes Google Cast support, `play-services-ads` contains ads support, etc. If you aren't using any of them currently, why do you even have that dependency?